# How can I display firebase details in a separate page in Angularfire2

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, angularfire, angularfire2

I have a static firebase database which have schema looks below. 
This screenshot is a small part of it. There are many cities listed with basic info in my database.

[image: firebase database schema]

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CityPage} from '../city/city';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  cityPage = CityPage;

  cityinfo: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, af: AngularFire) {
    this.cityinfo = af.database.list('/cityinfo');
  }

}
```

I listed firebase items in a grid at home page.

**home.html**

```
  <div [navPush]="cityPage" class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp" *ngFor="let item of cityinfo | async">
    <figure class="mdl-card__media">
      <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="" />
    </figure>
    {{ item.$key }}
  </div>
```

But my essential problem is;

I want to display city details (summary, geography, population, zipcode, image) information in a separate page ( in city page [ city.html ] ) when I clicked an image in grid at home.html

**city.html**

```
<ion-content padding class="recipe">
    <p> {{ item.summary }} </p>
    <p> {{ item.geography }} </p>
    <p> {{ item.population }} </p>
    <p> {{ item.zipcode }} </p>
    <img src="{{ item.image }}">
</ion-content>
```

For example, if I click Charlotte city image at home page, I want to display Charlotte city's information in city.html or if I click Raleigh city's picture, I want to display information in city.html

Any help would be appreciated, if someone can help me to success it. I couldn't do that.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the city information as a parameter to you city page.

Modify the city figure html to call a function that'll do that, so when you click/tap that image it'll pass the current item of your foreach to the function that'll do the work, like this:

```
<div [navPush]="cityPage" class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--2dp" *ngFor="let item of cityinfo | async">
  <figure class="mdl-card__media" (click)="showCityInfo(item)"> //CAN USE (tap) TOO.
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" alt="" />
  </figure>
  {{ item.$key }}
</div>
```

In your Home.ts create that function and, using navController, push the city page with the city info.

```
showCityInfo(item) {
  this.navCtrl.push(CityPage, item);
}
```

in your citypage, grab the city info with navparams and save it in a variable

```
//IMPORT NAVPARAMS FROM IONIC-ANGULAR
cityInfo: any;

constructor(public navPrms: NavParams){
  this.cityInfo = navPrms.data; //here you'll get the data you passed from your home.ts
}
```

just populate your city.html with your city info

```
<ion-content padding class="recipe">
  <p> {{ cityInfo.summary }} </p>
  <p> {{ cityInfo.geography }} </p>
  <p> {{ cityInfo.population }} </p>
  <p> {{ cityInfo.zipcode }} </p>
  <img src="{{ cityInfo.image }}">
</ion-content>
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. It worked well. Just one thing happened unexpected. When I clicked an image, opened two detail pages one page on top of another. One have detailed info and another is blank. I have removed [navPush]="recipePage"  then it worked well. Fast and great solution for me.